# Gradle remove version number from the dependency name

Tags: java, gradle, jar, derby

I would like to use derbyrun.jar created by the Apache Derby project in my application in order to run a derby database as a Windows or Linux service.

The problem is that derbyrun.jar references in its manifest other derby jars without any version number in their names, like  `Class-Path: derby.jar derbyclient.jar derbytools.jar derbynet.jar`. While my application (with many subprojects) uses "maven/gradle" format `derby-10.13.1.1.jar, derbyclient-10.13.1.1.jar, etc.`.

Is there a simple way in gradle to name those derby jars without a version number, like

```
compile("org.apache.derby:derby:10.11.1.1") {
  artifact {
    name = 'derby'
  }
}
```

that should result in just `derby.jar`.

I do not like an idea of renaming `derby-10.13.1.1.jar` into `derby.jar` in a separate task as we reference those artifact names in many places using `configurations.runtime`, etc. (e.g. when deploying or creating manifest files for our own jars). And this renaming approach seems to complicate the script unnecessary (+ all the future maintenance effort when the derby version will be changed).

Is there a better way to achieve this? Sure, the mentioned above `artifact { name = 'derby' }` does not remove the version number from the jar's file name.

Comment: compile 'org.apache.derby:derby:+' try this

Comment: @InjuredThePatient, it will simply download the latest version resulting in the same result as before derby-10.13.1.1.jar.

Comment: Maybe a custom task of `JavaExec` type will solve the problem?

Comment: @Opal, maybe, but I do not see how. And how it shall simplify our script compared to any other mentioned above solutions using native gradle tasks, I do not see either. The "simplest" way, as of now, seems to simply duplicate those derby jars. Having one set with version numbers and the second set without those numbers.

Comment: What your usage scenario? I mean, how you use derby.jar?

Comment: @Opal, derbyrun.jar is used to run Derby database as a Windows service. Derbyrun.jar needs derbyclient.jar as a dependency (it is specified in its manifest file). Our application uses derbyclient-10.13.1.1.jar (as it is named by Gradle, by default) to connect to this derby database. Those -client jars are eventually the same. Is it clear? Or do I miss what is not clear to you?

Comment: And you need a task that will run this derby database, am I correct?

Comment: @Opal, no I need that derbyclient-10.13.1.1.jar is named derbyclient.jar and all configurations.compile, configurations.runtime, etc. gradle properties reference derbyclient.jar and not derbyclient-10.13.1.1.jar. So I need some sort of a task that will rename the jar and update all internal configurations references. And I am really surprised that there is no such option (to name the dependecy .jar the way you like it) using the standard gradle dependency management. Hope this clarifies. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately not - you suggest a solution: _I need to rename_ whereas the problem scenario is e.g.: _I need to run derby client for tests from gradle as a task_. That's why I am asking about scenario.

Comment: @Opal. I really don't know how to describe it better... "derbyrun.jar is used to run Derby database as a Windows service. Derbyrun.jar needs derbyclient.jar as a dependency (it is specified in its manifest file). Our application uses derbyclient-10.13.1.1.jar (as it is named by Gradle, by default) to connect to this database. Those -client jars are eventually the same.". That Windows service is created and maintained by our application. So our application needs to deploy two same jars, but under different names. Isn't it already a problem? Maybe it isn't a big problem, but I think it is bad...